# Have battery status only show in menu bar when running on battery power

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, battery

I use my MacBook Pro plugged in to power and an external monitor 90% of the time, and thus the little charged battery indicator in the menubar is useless. However when I'm not on wall power, is there a way to have it show up? When I have that menu item disabled, my MacBook doesn't give me any low battery warnings, and just shuts down (it's happened several times).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [SlimBatteryMonitor](http://www.orange-carb.org/SBM/) (free, donations accepted, not nagware) instead of the default menu item for the battery status.

SBM can be configured to *almost* disappear from the menu bar when fully charged.

If that isn't enough for you, you could run a `launchd` script every few minutes to check the status of the battery, to see whether or not it is fully charged, and act accordingly:

- If the battery is fully charged, quit SlimBatteryMonitor (if it is running)
- If the battery is NOT fully charged, run SlimBatteryMonitor (if it isn't already running)

I am actually doing something like this already. I just uploaded the necessary files to 
https://github.com/tjluoma/slimbatterymonitor

Comment: Superb! I think the small blank space in between icons in my menu bar is a small price to pay.